# Prototype of a scanner/tokenizer for Bitmap Distribution Format parser

Tags: parsing, rust

Instead of the obvious decision, parsing using given `std::io::Lines/std::io::Bytes` or crates like `nom`, I decided to explore writing my own specialized scanner that operates on `std::io::BufRead`.

I have two (self inflicted) problems.

Firstly, scanner must operate on bytes, utf8 validation given by rust `String` would really work just as well, but is "overkill", this is what [`BDF 2.1`](https://www.x.org/docs/BDF/bdf.pdf) specification says about it:

> Character bitmap information will be distributed in an USASCII-encoded, human-readable form. Each file
> is encoded in the printable characters (octal 40 through 176) of USASCII plus carriage return and linefeed.
> Each file consists of a sequence of variable-length lines. Each line is terminated either by a carriage return
> (octal 015) and linefeed (octal 012) or by just a linefeed.

Secondly, I want to avoid as many "needless" allocations as possible, in other words, allow the user of the scanner to manage allocations. While this can be seen as premature optimization, I'd like if we looked at it as a zero-cost abstraction or all the power to the user or maybe even just a different code style from what is common in rust.

Criticism I'm looking for is specifically more focused on code readability and managing errors with constraints above than performance, although if anything I wrote here is a pessimization, I'd like to know about it aswell.

Note that I'm aware that "documentation" on Scanner methods is horrible, that is because its not documentation, just exactly my thoughts on them.

```
use std::{
    error, fmt,
    io::{BufRead, ErrorKind},
};

pub type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Error>;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Error {
    StdIo(std::io::Error),
    UnexpectedByte { current: u8, expected: u8 },
    Eof,
}

impl fmt::Display for Error {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match *self {
            Error::StdIo(ref e) => e.fmt(f),
            Error::UnexpectedByte { current, expected } => {
                write!(f, "Read byte {:#0X} while expecting {:#0X}", current, expected)
            },
            Error::Eof => write!(f, "Reached end of file"),
        }
    }
}

impl error::Error for Error {
    fn source(&self) -> Option<&(dyn error::Error + 'static)> {
        match *self {
            Error::StdIo(ref e) => Some(e),
            Error::UnexpectedByte { .. } => None,
            Error::Eof => None,
        }
    }
}

impl From<std::io::Error> for Error {
    fn from(e: std::io::Error) -> Error {
        Error::StdIo(e)
    }
}

pub struct Scanner<R> {
    r: R,
}

impl<R> Scanner<R>
where
    R: BufRead,
{
    /// Peek at a next byte
    ///
    /// This is the root of all functionality provided in this scanner.
    ///
    /// Given the fact that we will only perform very small reads (1 byte, yes), this might be whole
    /// 1 boolean check (observation, not aim: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/buffered.rs.html#265)
    /// if BufReader buffer is empty, more efficient than Read::read(std::slice::from_mut(&mut byte)),
    /// besides, we cannot even peek at buffer without fill_buf (guaranteed to be filled or eof'd), 
    /// or BufReader::buffer (not guaranteed to be filled)
    fn peek(&mut self) -> Result<u8> {
        loop {
            return match self.r.fill_buf() {
                Ok(bytes) => bytes.first().copied().ok_or(Error::Eof),
                Err(ref e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::Interrupted => continue,
                Err(e) => Err(Error::StdIo(e)),
            };
        }
    }

    /// Could instead just be implemented as `self.r.read_exact(std::slice::from_mut(&mut byte))`?
    fn advance(&mut self) -> Result<u8> {
        let byte = self.peek()?;
        self.r.consume(1);
        Ok(byte)
    }

    /// Same as advance, but instead asserts that byte matches, does nothing otherwise,
    /// useful for optional characters like `\r` and for enforcing structure, for example, BDF
    /// format tokens are separated by spaces, `scanner.skip(b' ')?` ensures that parsing stops
    /// if space is missing.
    pub fn skip(&mut self, expected: u8) -> Result<()> {
        let current = self.peek()?;
        if current != expected {
            Err(Error::UnexpectedByte { current, expected })
        } else {
            self.r.consume(1);
            Ok(())
        }
    }

    /// Unlike skip, operates on multiple bytes; naming inconsistency?
    ///
    /// This is also, unlike skip, not optional, if byte doesn't exist somewhere in the middle,
    /// reader is likely to be in unpredictable state.
    pub fn consume(&mut self, bytes: &[u8]) -> Result<()> {
        for &expected in bytes {
            let current = self.advance()?;
            if current != expected {
                return Err(Error::UnexpectedByte { current, expected });
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    /// BDF keyword
    ///
    /// Writes keyword into provided buffer until the end, returns length of it in a result.
    ///
    /// It is a good idea to preallocate your buffer beforehand, most BDF fonts I looked at don't
    /// have tokens longer than 64 bytes, I preallocate 128 just in case.
    ///
    /// If length is 0, keyword is missing entirely or data is malformed (multiple spaces between
    /// tokens and so on), but that's your job to deal with it.
    pub fn keyword(&mut self, buf: &mut Vec<u8>) -> Result<usize> {
        let mut read = 0;
        loop {
            match self.peek()? {
                // Keyword must be SCREAMCASE ASCII ONLY
                byte @ 0x41 ..= 0x5A => {
                    buf.push(byte);
                    read += 1;
                    self.r.consume(1);
                },
                _ => break,
            }
        }
        Ok(read)
    }

    // TODO: strings, bit arrays, arbitrary reads till eol...
}

impl<R> From<R> for Scanner<R>
where
    R: BufRead,
{
    fn from(r: R) -> Scanner<R> {
        Scanner { r }
    }
}

static FONT: &[u8] = b"STARTFONT 2.1\n?";

fn main() {
    let mut scanner = Scanner::from(FONT);
    let mut buf: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(128);

    // forced keyword, reader must start on keyword or we leave
    match scanner.keyword(&mut buf) {
        Ok(0) => panic!("No keyword?"),
        Ok(_) => {
            print!("{}", std::str::from_utf8(&buf).unwrap());
            buf.clear();
        },
        Err(e) => panic!("{:?}", e),
    }

    // forced skip of a single space
    // this "parser" is anal about there being a single space for now, but this could be
    // used as optional skip until all spaces are gone if that is required.
    match scanner.skip(b' ') {
        Ok(_) => {
            print!("<SPACE>");
        },
        Err(e) => panic!("{:?}", e),
    }

    // BDF is either 2.1 or we leave.
    match scanner.consume(b"2.1") {
        Ok(_) => {
            print!("2.1");
        },
        Err(e) => panic!("{:?}", e),
    }

    // optionally avoid legacy, errors like eof will be noticed in non-optional tokens
    if let Ok(_) = scanner.skip(b'\r') {
        print!("<CR>");
    }

    // forced skip of newline as we finished with this BDF item.
    match scanner.skip(b'\n') {
        Ok(_) => println!("<LF>"),
        Err(e) => panic!("{:?}", e),
    }

    // begin parsing next BDF item, but fail (panics won't exist in real parser)
    match scanner.keyword(&mut buf) {
        Ok(0) => panic!("No keyword?"),
        Ok(_) => {
            print!("{}", std::str::from_utf8(&buf).unwrap());
            buf.clear();
        },
        Err(e) => panic!("{:?}", e),
    }
}
```

Result of this example:

```
STARTFONT<SPACE>2.1<LF>
thread 'main' panicked at 'No keyword?', src/bin/main.rs:182:18
```

As you can see, this works as expected and I believe that code above is hard to improve, I want to be really sure about that, though.